# MessageBodyWriter not found

Tags: spring, tomcat, jersey-2.0

Upgraded jersey from 1.8 to jersey 2.33.

Here's a trace

```
19:58:29,122 [ INFO] -1:LoginDaoImpl.getUserByUserName: - OUT dao : LoginDaoImpl app side getUserByUserName method.
```

```
10-Apr-2023 19:58:29.164 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class in.wm.common.authentication.models.UserDetailsJson, genericType=class in.wm.common.authentication.models.UserDetailsJson.
```

```
19:58:29,184 [ INFO] -1:GenericException.toResponse: - In Generic Exception Handler - WM-APP
```

```
19:58:29,184 [ INFO] -1:GenericException.toResponse: - , Exception message is:--HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
```

```
10-Apr-2023 19:58:29.207 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class in.wm.common.util.BaseResponse, genericType=class in.wm.common.util.BaseResponse.
```

```
10-Apr-2023 19:58:29.207 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception.
```

```
19:58:29,235 [ INFO] -1:SecurityFilter.doFilter: - Exception: while validating the token  javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
```

Any Suggestions,  Have added @JsonProperties annotation over respective POJO.

Made all the lib , import changed. Added all required dependacies now getting error  MessageBodyWriter not found

Context:

Java 8

Jersey 2.33 version of all dependencies, Tomcat9, added Moxy, server, client dependencies

Any Suggestions,  Have tried @XmlRootElemt in pojo @JsonProperties annotation over respective POJO.